# How to convert JSON Object to Java HashMap using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson

I have JSON structure like this:

```
{   
    "person": 
    {
        "name": "snoop",
        "age": "22",
        "sex": "male"
    }
}
```

And beans like this:

```
public class Person {
    HashMap<String,String> map;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I want all key and value from JSON to be filled inside map from Person class.
I do not want to create bean for each key from JSON like `int age`, `String name` etc.

I have tried following example and it worked for normal JSON structure like below:

```
{
    "type": "Extends",
    "target": "application",
    "ret": "true"
}
```

and program is:

```
String jsonString = "{\"type\": \"Extends\", \"target\": \"application\", \"ret\":\"true\" }";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    Map<String, Object> carMap = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
    });

    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : carMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("key=" + entry.getKey() + " and value=" + entry.getValue());
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above program works fine and gets values in Hashmap from JSON. But in case of previously mentioned Hashmap:

```
{   
    "person": 
    {
        "name": "snoop",
        "age": "22",
        "sex": "male"
    }
}
```

it doesn't work and gives `NullPointerException` as Hashmap is null.

Is there any way we can use Jackson API to populate Hashmap within Person class.

Comment: "doesn't work" *specifically how*?

Comment: It gives null hasmap value.

Comment: Try this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066196/how-to-convert-json-array-to-java-hashmap-using-jackson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I'm not able to unwrap and serialize a Java map using the Jackson Java library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043587/why-im-not-able-to-unwrap-and-serialize-a-java-map-using-the-jackson-java-libra)

Answer (score 3):

use `JsonAnyGetter` and `JsonAnySetter` annotation here.

E.g:

Perosn class:

```
@JsonRootName("person")
class Person {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setMap(String name, String value) {
        map.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Deserialization logic:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
Person person = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Person.class);
```