# Convert JSONArrays into Map using Java

Tags: java, json

Trying to write a java class which convert JSON into Map by giving key. Sample method format and steps are below:

```
  public Map<String, Map<String, String> convert(String jsonBody, String key){
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
  Map<String, String> singleEntry = new HashMap<String, String>();
//Iterator<String> --get key from jsonBody
while(itr.hasNext()){
for(upto arary count){
 singleEntry.put(jsonBody.getKey(i), jsonBody.getValue(i));
  }
  dataMap.put(itr.next(), singleEntry);
 }
 System.out.println(dataMap);

 return data;
}
```

Sample JSON

```
[
{
    "id": 146,
    "Name": "John",
    "LastName": "Mack",

},
{
    "id": 148,
    "Name": "Sam",
    "LastName": "Rick",
}

 ]
```

Expected Output: 
id -146, {id=146, Name = John, LastName =Mack}
id -148, {id=148, Name = Sam, LastName =Rick}

Please suggest best API and correct approach. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/) for how to convert a json node to a Map.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066196/how-to-convert-json-array-to-java-hashmap-using-jackson) about how to convert the json array to a map.

Comment: In both examples, POJO used while in my case array elements are dynamic so I cant use POJO, It should be generic method which convert any JSON Into map on the basis of key.

Comment: The first example converts to a Map<String, String>. You could loop through your json array, converting each JsonNode into Map<String, String> and then adding it to the big map?